# Convert block of loop into a list comprehension

Tags: python

I want to convert this snippet

```
for val in G[k]:
    if val in span[k]:
        result.append((val,col))
    elif val in G[k] and val not in span[k] and S[val][k] != 'col':
        result.append((val,row))
```

into a list comprehension. But this gives me error:

```
[(val,col) if val in span[k] else (val,row) if val in G[k] and val not in span[k] and S[val][k] != 'col' for val in G[k]]
```

So what would be the correct syntax, if there is i.e.

Comment: Don't do it. It's MUCH less readable than the normal loop - at least if you write it as a one-liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using conditional expressions without an `else` part; that's a syntax error.

The correct translation is:

```
[(val,col) if val in span[k] else (val,row) for val in G[k] if val in span[k] or S[val][k] != 'col']
```

e.g. filter out anything that doesn't match your two conditions first, and select between the two branches for values that *do* result in something added to the output.

I simplified the conditions; there was some redundant testing in the second expression (`val in G[k]` is *always* true for a loop over `G[k]` and if `val in span[k]` is *not* `True` then the inverse `val not in span[k]` is certainly `True` as well and doesn't need to be tested for again.

Personally, I find the explicit `for` loop more readable, but you can at least simplify it in the same manner:

```
for val in G[k]:
    if val in span[k]:
        result.append((val,col))
    elif S[val][k] != 'col':
        result.append((val,row))
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn. Is it true that comprehensions work faster than the usual loop?

Comment: @user2290820: Don't forget that maintenance also requires effort. Don't optimize for speed prematurely if the price of not being able to read the code is going to bite you later on.

Comment: @user2290820: A list comprehension can be faster than a `for` loop with `.append()`, yes, but your list comp here has to test `val in span[k]` *twice*.

Comment: Cool,sure. The comments include the simpler readable logic. how about that?

Comment: If you can keep the comments updated, then sure, go knock yourself out! :-)

Comment: Ok wait.the span[k] (index search is linear right?) but here span[k] is Theta(1) ; span is a dictionary. Is still using it twice is not as fast as the simple loop?

Comment: @user2290820: indexing into a dictionary (so *just* the `span[k]` operation) is constant cost, but `in somelist` is linear. What type are the values of `span[k]` here? Even if the cost is constant, you now incur that cost twice.

Comment: Fine I'll go with the loop. its a dictionary value

Comment: If this is on a time-critical path in your code, I'd test the timings (with the `timeit` module), otherwise I'd just use a `for` loop myself.

Comment: Great martjin.will test it out actually and choose whichever is faster. Yes it becomes time critical as num of elements increase massively

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
[(val,col) if val in span[k] else (val,row)
 if val in G[k] and val not in span[k] and S[val][k] != 'col'
 for val in G[k]]
```

to

```
[(val,col) if val in span[k] else (val,row)
 for val in G[k]
 if val in G[k] and val not in span[k] and S[val][k] != 'col' ]
```

**Rule of thumb** If there is an `if` before `for` in comprehension, it must have an `else`.